# Stripe: how to omit 3D Secure?

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

We have created an iOS app for short rental owners with the objective of holding rental deposits on a credit card during a few days. The user can decide to capture the payment if there is something broken in the flat.

This app has been made with Stripe.

We encounter the following issue: when the user enters his client's credit card in the app for holding a deposit of about 300€ for exemple, Stripe doesn't accept to continue the operation without 3D Secure verification.

While in the same time, it works perfectly without 3D Secure when doing this operation on the Stripe Dashboard, with the same credit card, the same amount and the same location.

We would like to omit 3D secure in our iOS app, just like the Stripe Dashboard.

How is it possible ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which kind of Stripe account are you using? Express? Custom? Also, you should look into your dashboard settings.

Comment: @SwiftUser how do I know my account type ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended, you should build your integration to [support 3D Secure authentication](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=ios&ui=custom), even when placing a hold to [capture later](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later).